# How to reference a class from other class with foreign key in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, object, foreign-keys

I would like to have in the object UserPassword a field with a Object User,that has all the attributes of User(uuid,name,rol...)

Code of UserPassword :

```
 [Key]
        public Guid Uuid { get; set; }
        public Guid UserID { get; set; }
        public Guid PasswordID { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public int Permissions { get; set; }

        public User User { get; set; }
        public Password Password { get; set; }
```

Code of User:

```
[Key]
    public Guid Uuid { get; set; }
    [StringLength(40, ErrorMessage = "The Name value cannot exceed 40 characters. ")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Rol { get; set; }
    [StringLength(4096, ErrorMessage = "The PublicKey value cannot exceed 4096 characters. ")]
    public string PublicKey { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime RemovedDate { get; set; }

    public List<UserPassword> userPassword { get; set; }
```

Code of DBContext:

```
public class PasswordManagementDbContext : DbContext
{
    public PasswordManagementDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Password>().HasMany(x => x.userPassword).WithOne(x => x.Password).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(x => x.userPassword).WithOne(x => x.User).IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserPassword>().HasOne<User>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.UserID).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserPassword>().HasOne<Password>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.PasswordID).IsRequired();
    }


    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Password> Passwords { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserPassword> UserPasswords { get; set; }
```

The goal is to can extract an User from the UserPassword class, like this :

```
string name = userPassword.User.Name;
```

Comment: Because I save my data objects in sql server

Comment: And why you would like to have a circular reference like that?

Comment: I would like to have the object User inside the UserPassword because I need to have all the attributes in the client side.

Comment: You only tell what you want. Not where you experience a problem.

Comment: Do you mean how to add UserPassword into the database successfully? Or you haved  add UserPassword into the database successfully, just want to know how to use linq to extract an User from the UserPassword class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A work demo is below,you can refer to it:

User.cs:

```
public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Uuid { get; set; }
        [StringLength(40, ErrorMessage = "The Name value cannot exceed 40 characters. ")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Rol { get; set; }
        [StringLength(4096, ErrorMessage = "The PublicKey value cannot exceed 4096 characters. ")]
        public string PublicKey { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime RemovedDate { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserPassword> Password { get; set; }// navigation property to Password 
    }
```

Password.cs:

```
public class Password
    {
        public Guid PasswordID { get; set; }
        public string rol { get; set; }//other thing you want...
        public virtual ICollection<UserPassword> User { get; set; } //navigation property to User
    }
```

DbContext.cs:

```
public class GuidUserContext : DbContext
    {
        public GuidUserContext (DbContextOptions<GuidUserContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<GuidUser.Models.UserPassword> UserPassword { get; set; }

        public DbSet<GuidUser.Models.User> User { get; set; }

        public DbSet<GuidUser.Models.Password> Password { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller.cs:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly GuidUserContext _context;

        public HomeController(GuidUserContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            string name = _context.UserPassword.Select(u=>u.User.Name).First();
            return View();
        }
}
```

result:

[image]